# Unhighlight the selected text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code to highlight all the words which user gives

```
 function highlightWord(root, word) {
     textNodesUnder(root).forEach(highlightWords);

     function textNodesUnder(root) {
         var walk = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false),
             text = [],
             node;
         while (node = walk.nextNode()) text.push(node);
         return text;
     }

     function highlightWords(n) {
         for (var i;
             (i = n.nodeValue.indexOf(word, i)) > -1; n = after) {
             var after = n.splitText(i + word.length);
             var highlighted = n.splitText(i);
             var span = document.createElement('span');
             span.className = "spanClass";
             span.style.backgroundColor = "red";
             span.appendChild(highlighted);
             after.parentNode.insertBefore(span, after);
         }
     }
 }
```

how do i unhighlight all the words or when i tapped on partcular word? Am kind of new to programming.Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: If all your highlighted words are wrapped with the same type of element you can simply remove all of the spans creating the highlight effect.

Comment: can you not change the style of the `node`, rather than inserting a `span`?
Then to unhighlight you could just set the `node.style.backgroundColor = '';`

Comment: @Lix yes i got the all elements using **getElementsByClassName**.then i got the parent node as `p = element.parentNode`.then i removed it from the dom as `p.removechild(element)`.but its deleting the content too from the page.any solution?